# Does the UB1002 mixer allow for headphones with an impedance of 250ohm?

Tags: headphones

My set up will be an asus rog phoebus soundcard (which allows for up to 250ohm) and an Eurorack UB1002 mixer, where i feed in the signals from the computer and my bass amplifier. I am then looking to buy a pair of beyerdynamic dt 770 pro. I was wondering if having a mixer would mess up my system, when using high impedance headphones. Maybe the sound will be too low, or something.

I have tried looking at the spec sheet for the UB1002 which is here: http://www.behringer.com/assets/UB1002_P0181_S_EN.pdf
But i am not totally shure what i should be looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Maximum power transfer occurs when the impedance of a device matches the impedance of the source...

Think of it this way: if source impedance is much higher than the device then you risk damage due to overload, like a blown speaker.  If source impedance is lower than the device, it is kind of like the resistance of trying to start a 5-speed in second gear...

Your mixer specs list (at the bottom) a headphone output (output source) impedance of 150R (ohms), and I would guess around 100 milliwatts. The DT770 Pro headphones (device) are rated at 250R...

In this case, I think you will be fine because most people don't monitor their music at full volume; so you should have a bit of extra headroom on your headphone output to compensate for the mismatched load.  This is my best opinion.  If in the end you are unsatisfied you can always purchase an inexpensive headphone amp.  :)

Please understand that this idea of mismatched loads can be completely safe because we are dealing with low power, but it can become very dangerous when larger amplifiers are supplying much higher wattage through much lower resistances in speakers.  I'm sure you are aware of this because of your bass amp, I just don't want to put the wrong idea out there.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

It won't "mess up" your system, the 250 ohm ones take a more powerful amp t get the same loudness. The 770 pro has 80 ohm and 32 ohm versions if you're concerned about volume. That said, the 1002 is still a professional piece of kit, and I don't remember my 802 having any issues driving 64 ohm headphones quite loud a while back.